# Woocommerce to Google Sheets Webhook - Multi-product oders

Tags: google-sheets, woocommerce, webhooks, google-sheets-api

I'm using the script below to import WooCommerce orders into Google Sheets via a webhook.
The data is importing as expected, however only the first product of each order is being presented. How would i amend the script to include multiple product names and product quantities for each order?*****

```
//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {

    var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
    var order_number = myData.number;
    var first_name = myData.billing.first_name;
    var last_name = myData.billing.last_name;
    var address = myData.billing.address_1;
    var town = myData.billing.city;
    var postcode = myData.billing.postcode;
    var product_name = myData.line_items[0].name;
    var product_qty = myData.line_items[0].quantity;
    var notes = myData.customer_note;
    var timestamp = new Date();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();


    sheet.appendRow([timestamp, order_number, first_name, last_name, address, town, postcode, product_name, product_qty, notes]);
}
```

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: It depends, how are you importing the data in `e.postData.contents`?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are doing fine.

The problem you are facing is because in a multi-product order, there are multiple variables in your JSON data with the name 'product title', so with your code, only the first product name is being read.

**Solution:**

In your code, replace your code

```
var product_name = myData.line_items[0].name;
```

With this code

```
for (var i = 0; i < myData.line_items.length; i++){ 
var product_name = myData.line_items[i].name;
var product_qty = myData.line_items[i].quantity;

quantity = quantity + product_qty;
if(i!=0)
{
 description = description + " || " + product_name + " x " + product_qty;
}
else
{
  description = product_name + " x " + product_qty;
}
}
```

This traverses through the JSON table, gets all product names, writes their quantities in front of them and then adds a little separator "||" between two different products.
Usman